# How can I convert following code to a vue js code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);

    function success(position) {

        var GEOCODING = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + position.coords.latitude + '%2C' + position.coords.longitude + '&language=en';

        $.getJSON(GEOCODING).done(function(location) {
            $('#country').html(location.results[0].address_components[5].long_name);
            $('#state').html(location.results[0].address_components[4].long_name);
            $('#city').html(location.results[0].address_components[2].long_name);
            $('#address').html(location.results[0].formatted_address);
            $('#latitude').html(position.coords.latitude);
            $('#longitude').html(position.coords.longitude);
        })
         $.ajax({
          url: 'post/filter/',
          data: {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lon: position.coords.longitude,
          },
          type: "POST",
          dataType: 'json',

        });
    }

    function error(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
```

This is my code. I need to pass latitude and longitude as an ajax request to the server side to get values.. By using this code I am able to do so.

My vue js code is

```
<div id="categorie">
  <div>{{vector.name}}</div>
</div>
<script>
categorie = new Vue({
    el: '#categorie',
    data: {
        vector: {},
    },
 methods: { 

            search_category: function success(position) {
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
            var GEOCODING = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + position.coords.latitude + '%2C' + position.coords.longitude + '&language=en';

            $.getJSON(GEOCODING).done(function(location) {
                $('#country').html(location.results[0].address_components[5].long_name);
                $('#state').html(location.results[0].address_components[4].long_name);
                $('#city').html(location.results[0].address_components[2].long_name);
                $('#address').html(location.results[0].formatted_address);
                $('#latitude').html(position.coords.latitude);
                $('#longitude').html(position.coords.longitude);
            })
             var filter = {};
             var self=this;
             filter['category'] = position.coords.latitude;
            filter['subcategory'] = position.coords.longitude;
            $.ajax({
              "url": "post/filter",
               data: filter,
              dataType: "JSON",
              type: "POST",
              success: function(e) {
                  self.vector = e.data;
                console.log(e);
              },

            });
          }
        }

})
</script>
```

But when I use vue js code I am not able to send ajax request? Can any body please solve my issue Can someone please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you clarify what "I am not able to send ajax request" means?  Do you get an error?  What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

The vue way of working with async request for your problem is shown below:

```
this.$http.get(GEOCODING).then(response=> {
   // here your data is in response 
}).catch(error => {
   // TODO: handle your error here...
})
```

But thing to remember, above feature is available in `vue-resource` package. I suggest you go through [this](https://laracasts.com/series/learning-vue-step-by-step/episodes/11) very nice tutorial in @laracasts website: https://laracasts.com/series/learning-vue-step-by-step/episodes/11

Now I hope you'll have no further issues in async request in vue. And the conversion of your code in vue js is here in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jcuytpx2/ Happy Coding :)

```js
category = new Vue({
    el: '#category',
    data: () => ({
        vector: {},
        address: {
            country: '',
            state: '',
            city: '',
            address: ''
        },
    }),

    methods: {
        search_category(position) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
                    var GEOCODING = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + position.coords.latitude + '%2C' + position.coords.longitude + '&language=en';
                    this.google_response(GEOCODING).then(response => {
                        this.address.country = response.results[0].address_components[5].long_name
                        this.address.state = response.results[0].address_components[4].long_name
                        this.address.city = response.results[0].address_components[2].long_name
                        this.address.address = response.results[0].formatted_address

                        let filter = {}
                        filter.category = response.coords.latitude
                        filter.subcategory = response.coords.longitude

                        /**** implement your methods here....
       this.$http.post('post/filter', filter).then(response => {
         this.vector = response.data
       }).catch(error => {
        // TODO: Handle error here
       })
       *****/
                    }).catch(error => {
                        // TODO: Handle error here
                    })
                })
            },

            google_response(GEOCODING) {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    this.$http.get(GEOCODING).then(response => {
                        resolve(JSON.parse(response.bodyText))
                    }).catch(error => {
                        reject(error)
                    })
                })
            }
    }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/1.3.4/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="category">
    <div>{{vector.name}}</div>
    <hr>
    <strong>
  Country: {{ address.country }}<br>
  State: {{ address.state }}<br>
  City: {{ address.city }}<br>
  Address: {{ address.address }}
 </strong>
    <hr>
    <button @click="search_category">
        Search
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: how to automatically detect without searching

Comment: What do you want to detect automatically?